Editing/ formatting several URL's in python within a string
Please help! I am very new at this. I have a string of url's of which I am trying to remove the same part of each one. For example:
old urls
http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/30/421/test-url-link-HuEB5k.jpg 
http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/24/579/this-test-link-2-D3MnkU.jpg

Edited form remove end portion with text caption before .jpg
http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/30/421/HuEB5k.jpg 
http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/24/579/D3MnkU.jpg

Heres what I am trying but I cant get all the urls to adjust to the same format
import_re
domain_str = 'http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/30/421/test-url-link-HuEB5k.jpg, http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/24/579/test-url-link-2-D3MnkU.jpg, http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/30/421/test-url-link-3-kJ65Vbe.jpg'
matches = re.findall('(https?:\/\/\w*\.\w*\/?)',domain_str)
altered_domains = [re.sub("test-url-link-", domain_str)]
print(altered_domains)


There are some errors in your code, but can you tell us the rules of what you are trying to do? Something like: I would like to remove the text following the last backslash up until the last - there is? Or to change the last part of the URL to just letters and numbers preceding .jpg?

Take a look at this regular expression if you really want to use regular expressions for this. The answers below will probably be better :). (.*(?=/)).*?([\w\.]+$) https://regex101.com/r/rRuQfz/1

Yes, I want to remove the text starting from after the last / until the last -.

If the format of your URLs is as well-defined as your sample data suggests then there's no need for a regular expression.
You just need to find the last occurrence of "/" and the last occurrence of "-". Then you can reconstruct the URL with a couple of slices.
For example:
url = "http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/30/421/test-url-link-HuEB5k.jpg"

ls = url.rindex("/") + 1
ld = url.rindex("-") + 1

newurl = url[:ls] + url[ld:]

print(newurl)

Output:
http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/30/421/HuEB5k.jpg

If you really want to use re then:
if g := re.search(r"^(.*)/.*-(.*)$", url):
    print("{}/{}".format(*g.groups()))

...will give the same result

Oh wow so much better thank you! How do I do multiple URL at once?

@user25301068 wrap the ls, ld, and newurl declarations in a for loop and iterate over a list of urls

I like @SIGHUP's answer, but here's a solution if you're dead-set on using regex
import re

urls = [
    'http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/30/421/test-url-link-HuEB5k.jpg',
    'http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/24/579/this-test-link-2-D3MnkU.jpg',
]

altered_domains = [re.sub('[a-z0-9]+-', '', url) for url in urls]

print(altered_domains)
>>> ['http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/30/421/HuEB5k.jpg', 'http://cdn4.abc//uploads/thumbnails/24/579/D3MnkU.jpg']

The regex pattern '[a-z0-9]+-' looks for one or more characters a-z or 0-9 followed by a dash '-', so it should work assuming your "captions" are always a combination of lowercase characters and numbers which end in a dash.
